# Unable to install NVM on my Mac. Keeps getting (7) Couldn't connect to server

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, nvm

As the title states, I can't seem to install NVM on my mac. I run this command:

`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.11.1/install.sh | bash`

but I get this

`0curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server`

Any ideas guys? Would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you on a vpn or behind a corporate firewall?

Comment: @r3wt - Nope, I'm using wifi